# Our INSERTs use REPEATABLEREAD hint. What effect does this have?

Tags: sql, t-sql, isolation-level, navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav

When profiling our Microsoft Dynamics NAV application with SQL Server Profiler, I get `INSERT`s with the `REPEATABLEREAD` hint.

What effect does the `REPEATABLEREAD` hint has on an `INSERT` statement?

In [SQL Server 2012 - How does "Repeatable Read" isolation level work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238059/sql-server-2012-how-does-repeatable-read-isolation-level-work) the `REPEATABLEREAD` hint is described, but this seems to apply to SELECTs only.

Extra info:

- Not all INSERTs have the `REPEATABLEREAD` hint, so maybe Microsoft
  Dynamics NAV application issues the hint under specific
  circumstances.
- The INSERTs are simple INSERT statement (no SELECT INTO or JOINs).
  The execution plan also shows a simple INSERT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2012 - How does "Repeatable Read" isolation level work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238059/sql-server-2012-how-does-repeatable-read-isolation-level-work) or perhaps [Does REPEATABLE_READ isolation prevent inserts for non-ranged queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960201/does-repeatable-read-isolation-prevent-inserts-for-non-ranged-queries)

Comment: Hi underscore_d, thanks for your info. The answer states 'No. The REPEATABLE_READ isolation level only guarantees that you will see the same data if you repeat the SELECT' So the hint is used for SELECT, not for INSERT

Comment: Do the insert statements have sub selects/subqueries?

Comment: Hi D Kramer, no its just a plane INSERT statement. Btw: I have updated my question based on your remark, thanks!

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15) states that the `REPEATABLEREAD` hint "_Specifies that a scan is performed with the same locking semantics as a transaction running at REPEATABLE READ isolation level. For more information about isolation levels, see [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)._" So, if the `INSERT` must scan indexes to check for dupes etc. - maybe that's what it means